# Display Custom Taxonomy Dropdown posts

Tags: debug

I wanna display posts of my custom taxonomy in a dropdown list, I mean I create a filter for taxonomies in my custom post type I have 2 different types which contains some sub-category & in that category I added some posts, the first taxonomy is "Types" and the second one is "Categories", so when I click the
taxonomy dropdown and select the sub-category for displaying the posts, nothing displays...

function diwp_arts_custom_post_type(){

```
$labels = array(
                 'name' => 'Arts',
                 'singular_name' => 'Art',
                 'add_new'    => 'Add New Post',
                 'add_new_item' => 'Enter Art Details',
                 'all_items' => 'All Arts',
                 'featured_image' => 'Add Feature Image',
                 'set_featured_image' => 'Set Feature Image',
                 'remove_featured_image' => 'Remove Feature Image'

               );


$args = array(    
                'public'      => true,
                'label'       => 'Arts',
                'labels'      => $labels,
                'description' => 'Arts is a collection of all Art and their info',
                'menu_icon'      => 'dashicons-art',    
                'supports'   => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
                'capability_type' => 'page',
                 
             );


register_post_type('arts', $args);
```

}

add_action( 'init', 'diwp_arts_custom_post_type' );

function wpdocs_create_book_tax() {
register_taxonomy( 'Types', 'arts', array(
'label'        => __( 'Types', 'textdomain' ),
'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'arts' ),
'hierarchical' => true,
) );

```
register_taxonomy( 'Categories', 'arts', array(
    'label'        => __( 'Categories', 'textdomain' ),
    'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'arts' ),
    'hierarchical' => true,
) );
```

}

add_action( 'init', 'wpdocs_create_book_tax', 0 );

function get_terms_dropdown_grade_level($taxonomies, $args){
$myterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
$output =""; //I can change this name (for my remembreance)!
$output .="Select Types";
foreach($myterms as $term){
$root_url = get_bloginfo('url');
$term_taxonomy=$term->taxonomy;
$term_slug=$term->slug;
$term_name =$term->name;
$link = $term_slug;
$output .="".$term_name."";
}
$output .="";
return $output;
}

```
function get_terms_dropdown_type($taxonomies, $args){
        $myterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
        $output ="<select name='Categories'>";
        $output .="<option value=''>Select Categories</option>";              
    foreach($myterms as $term){
                $root_url = get_bloginfo('url');
                $term_taxonomy=$term->taxonomy;
                $term_slug=$term->slug;
                $term_name =$term->name;
                $link = $term_slug;
                $output .="<option value='".$link."'>".$term_name."</option>";
        }
        $output .="</select>";
return $output;
}
```

I write this code into the sidebar.php file because I wanna show dropdown on all pages:

" method="get">
    
        'name','hide_empty'=>false);
        $select = get_terms_dropdown_grade_level($taxonomies, $args);
        $select = preg_replace("#]*)>#", "", $select);
        echo $select;
        ?>
        'name','hide_empty'=>false);
        $select = get_terms_dropdown_type($taxonomies, $args);

```
    $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select);
    echo $select;
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant see where in the code you want to have a taxonomy drop-down, and also what you want to do with this drop down. That also depends what values you want to use as option values.

But generally you can use `wp_dropdown_categories` to create a custom taxonomy drop-down.

```
wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'show_option_all' =>  'Show all arts',
    'taxonomy'        =>  'arts', // Name of the taxonomy or taxonomies to retrieve
    'name'            =>  'arts', // Value for the 'name' attribute of the select element
    'orderby'         =>  'name', // Order drop-down options
    'value_field'     =>  'slug', // Term field that should be used to populate the 'value' attribute of the option elements
                                  // Accepts: 'term_id', 'name', 'slug', 'term_group', 'term_taxonomy_id', 'taxonomy', 'description', 'parent', 'count'
    'selected'        =>  $selected, // Value of the option that should be selected. You need to add your own custom $selected
    'hierarchical'    =>  true // Whether to traverse the taxonomy hierarchy
) );
```

Comment: Actually, I wanna display posts of 2 taxonomies when I click the taxonomy it will show sub-category as a dropdown list & when I click on any sub-category it will show posts, first is "Types" & the other is "Categories", in these 2 taxonomies I put some posts and also in these taxonomies there are some sub-categories like, in first taxonomy "Type" I add these 4 sub-category; Science, Sports, Technology & World. In the second taxonomy "Categories" I add these 4 sub-category; General Knowledge, Machine Learning, History & Space. I think now you understand what is my problem...

Comment: `wp_dropdown_categories()` will get you only a select field of your taxonomy terms. What you do/what happens if you select an option in this field is up to you. It seems like you want to run a post query if something is selected. So you somehow need to listen to the change of the select field and than load your query. Maybe you want to rephrase or ask another question, becaus you didnt ask specifically that. Also please check the code formatting.

Comment: I edit my question and now you can see that I have created taxonomy dropdown but I have a little problem that is as I mentioned above, when I click the dropdown and select the sub-category it displays nothing just a blank page, so what is the solution of that problem